# Unable to install bcrypt on Digital Ocean node.js instance

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

I'm trying to use bcrypt for hashing passwords in a MEAN stack application. I'm hosting this on and Ubuntu 14 instance on Digital ocean and though my applicaiton runs fine locally, I'm getting a 502 bad gateway error from the server and I've narrowed the cause down to bcrypt.

I'm trying to install bcrypt on to a Digital Ocean node.js instance and get the following error:

```
root@mydomain:~# npm install -g bcrypt
-
> bcrypt@1.0.1 install /usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/releases/download/v1.0.1/bcrypt_lib-v1.0.1-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for bcrypt@1.0.1 and node@4.4.3 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/root/.node-gyp/4.4.3"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/.node-gyp"
make: Entering directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
make: *** No rule to make target `../.node-gyp/4.4.3/include/node/common.gypi', needed by `Makefile'.  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.30
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/usr/lib/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding' (1)
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v4.4.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.1 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the needed build tools. You should be able to install them via:

`sudo apt-get install build-essential`

You may also need to install Python 2.7 if it's not already installed.

Comment: thanks. I tried that but it wasn't working for me. I resolved my issue by updating node.js and then doing a local install on the project. Appreciate your help!

Comment: FWIW your solution "worked" because it found a pre-compiled binary tarball for that version of node. However if you need/want to compile an addon for either an addon other than `bcrypt` or you switch to some other version of node for which a pre-recompiled binary tarball does not already exist, you will need to install the build tools as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by updating my node.js instance to the latest version and then installing bcrypt in the project directory.